Import a namespace unqualified
I have a typescript module "mod" which contains namespaces like this:
export namespace system {
    interface SysThing {}
}
export namespace bob {
    interface Blah2 extend system.SysThing {}
}
export namespace fob {
    interface Blah3 extend system.SysThing {}
}

In another module "other_mod" I import "mod" like this:
import * as 'mod' from './mod';

Now, in "other_mod" I want to access the members of "system" directly, without the namespace prefix:
function A(f: mod.SysThing)...

However, other namespaces should be accessed fully qualified:
function B(f: mod.bob.Blah)...
function C(f: mod.fob.Blah)...

How to achieve that?
